# Why this C# code is not working , I wanna get My office 365 user details Using powershell objects

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I don't why this code didn't return any result. I wanna get my Org User details with PowerShell objects using c#. What could be the best method to get user details from my tenant using the PowerShell object in Visual Studio? I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and  .NET Core 5.0.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Security;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            String UserName = "xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
            String Password = "password";

            SecureString securestring = new SecureString();                     //Creating securestring object
            foreach (char c in Password)
                securestring.AppendChar(c);

            InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
            iss.ImportPSModule(new string[] { @"MSOnline" });                   //Importing Msonline module

            Runspace myRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);          //Creating runspace for the powershell commands to run
            myRunSpace.Open();
            PowerShell PS = PowerShell.Create();                                //Creating a powershell Object

            PSCredential Credential = new PSCredential(UserName, securestring); //Credentail object to connect with Msonline
            PS.AddCommand("Connect-MsolService");
            PS.AddParameter("Credential", Credential);
            PS.Invoke();

            PS.Commands.AddCommand("Get-MSOLUser");
            Collection<PSObject> MSOLUserList = PS.Invoke();

            Console.WriteLine(MSOLUserList.Count());
            foreach (PSObject user in MSOLUserList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(user.Members["UserPrincipalName"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `PS.Streams.Error` contain any records?

Comment: I'm facing this exception, how to resolve it.    Inner Exception 1: TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=6.7.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: Which Powershell version are you using? I'm also not sure if the MSOL module is compatible with .NET Core.

Comment: I'm Using Powershell 7.0

Comment: Cleared the exceptions, but don't know why it didn't return anything!

Comment: Damn, use Microsoft Graph API instead of this!

Comment: @filimonic , I have to use only powershell object to get user details. Don't know why it's not working